# How to conditionally (if/then) calculate column in R, following code is not working as expected in R

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement

I am coming to R from python panda code.

In my R dataframe I am trying to calculate column as follows:

```
s1$change_max1[s1['change_abs'] >0 ]= s1['high']-s1['close'] - s1['change_abs']
s1$change_max1[s1['change_abs']< 0 ]= s1['low'] -s1['close'] - s1['change_abs']
s1$change_max1[s1['change_abs']==0 ]= s1['change_abs']
```

It's not working as expected,
similar code in pandas work as expected.

```
s.loc[s1['change_abs']>0 ,'change_max']= s1['high']-(s1['close'] - s1['change_abs'])
s.loc[s1['change_abs']<0 ,'change_max']= s1['low'] -(s1['close'] - s1['change_abs'])
s.loc[s1['change_abs']==0,'change_max']= s1['change_abs']
```

it looks to me that on the right side in first snippet I can not use entire data frame, while left side is only a subset.

What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: Can you change the `[` to `[[` for the rhs.  Or may use `library(dplyr);s1 %>% mutate(change_max1 = case_when(change_abs > 0 ~ high -(close - change_abs), change_abs < 0~ low -(close - change_abs), change_abs == 0 ~ change_abs))`

Comment: ```Error in s1$change_max1[s1["change_abs"] == 0] = s1[["change_abs"]] :    NAs are not allowed in subscripted assignments
```

Comment: just updated the previous comment

Comment: If the columns was not already there, you could create the column as `NA_real_` before doing this i.e. `s1$change_max1 <- NA_real_; s1$change_max1[s1$change_abs == 0] <- s1$change_abs[s1$change_abs == 0]` or just `s1$changemax1[s1$change_abs==0] <- 0`

Comment: I think your rhs length will be different if you assignn `s1[['change_abs']]` i.e. the entire column.  You need both rhs and lhs to have the same condition

Answer (score 1):

The reason could be related to the length difference in the rhs and lhs i.e. rhs expression is full column length whereas lhs length is just a subset.

```
s1$change_max1 <- NA_real_
i1 <- sign(s1$change_abs)
s1$change_max1[i1 %in% 1 ] <- with(s1,  high - close - change_abs)[i1 %in% 1]
s1$change_max1[i1 %in% -1 ]<- with(s1, low  - close - change_abs)[i1 %in% -1]
s1$change_max1[i1 %in% 0 ] <- 0
```

---

Or may use a nested `ifelse` or `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)

s1 <- s1 %>% 
  mutate(change_max1 = case_when(
  change_abs > 0 ~  high -(close - change_abs), 
   change_abs < 0~ low -(close - change_abs),
   change_abs == 0 ~ 0))
```

Comment: I am getting error ```s1$change_max1[i1 == 1 ] <- with(s1,  high - close - change_abs)[i1 ==1]
Error in s1$change_max1[i1 == 1] <- with(s1, high - close - change_abs)[i1 ==  : 
  NAs are not allowed in subscripted assignments
> ```  However, your previous answer with dplyr works great ```s1<-s1 %>% dplyr::mutate(change_max = case_when(change_abs > 0 ~ high -(close - change_abs), change_abs < 0~ low -(close - change_abs), change_abs == 0 ~ change_abs))
```

Comment: @ErwinRingley can you show the values of `i1`  Does it have `NA`s?

Comment: @ErwinRingley try the updated one with `%in%` instead of `==`

Comment: Yes the updated one works great too!

Comment: both solutions work.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the code below answers the question. Untested, since there is no data.

```
i_zero <- which(s1$change_abs == 0)
s1$change_max1[i_zero] <- s1$change_abs[i_zero]
s1$change_max1[-i_zero] <- abs(s1$high - s1$close)[-i_zero] - s1$change_abs[-i_zero]
```

Comment: Yes! this one works too :)